# How can use NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey with Adobe Air?

Tags: ios, flash, apache-flex, air, adobe

Apple has rejected our application because we store files for offline viewing  under localStorage (/Documents)
This is an extract of the message, we received :

> Data that can be recreated but must persist for proper functioning of
>   your app - or because customers expect it to be available for offline
>   use - should be marked with the "do not back up" attribute. For NSURL
>   objects, add the NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute to prevent the
>   corresponding file from being backed up. For CFURLRef objects, use the
>   corresponding kCFURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute.

How can we do this with Adobe Air using Flex SDK 4.6?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a native extension for that: http://www.jampot.ie/ane/ane-ios-data-storage-set-donotbackup-attribute-for-ios5-native-extension/

Answer (score 1):

I know this is really old, but in case someone else has the same issue... Since AIR 3.6 there is no need for a native extension to prevent files from being backed up to the cloud.

There is a property in the File-Api for that, called `preventBackup`.
Usage:

```
var localFolder:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory;
localFolder.preventBackup = true;
```